# JavaScript: Fail to compare the index of for loop to another number

Tags: javascript

I have created two buttons:

```
<input id="myfile" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" >
<input id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="Upload">
```

With the following js:

```
$("#mysubmit").click(function() {
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'mybucket'}});
    var files_arr= $('#myfile').prop("files")
    var ErrNum = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<files_arr.length; i++){
        var params = {Key: files_arr[i].name, ContentType: files_arr[i].type, Body: files_arr[i]};
        bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
               console.log("Uploaded :: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');
        }).send(function(err, data) {
           if (err){
              ErrNum++;
           }
        });
        if (i === files_arr.length-1 && ErrNum > 0) {
           //do something
        }
        if (i === files_arr.length-1 && ErrNum === 0){
           alert("Success!");
        }
    };                     
});
```

I would like to wait until the last element uploaded and try to check how many errors occurred during uploading the files.

However, the if statement is not working because success is alerted first and the error shown in the console later.

I have also tried something like this outside the for loop:

```
if (ErrNum>0){
   //do something
}else{
   alert("Success!");
}
```

which is not working too.

Comment: The upload and send function runs asychronous. So it is finished after you check for the number of errors. Your approach isnt the "JS way". Why dont you react immediately when an error occurs  after you get the callback instead of incrementing a variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the upload method is asynchronous. 
The 2 if statements will be executed first. If you put this inside the callback it may or may not work. Because one may be finished first (that is not the last) when your loop is ended.

You should take a look at async, await or promises and read about this.

I think this should be an example of how to implement it:

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'mybucket'}});

function upload(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
            console.log("Uploaded :: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');
        }).send(function(err, data) {
            if (err){
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

$("#mysubmit").click(async function() {
    var files_arr= $('#myfile').prop("files");
    var ErrNum = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<files_arr.length; i++){
        var params = {Key: files_arr[i].name, ContentType: files_arr[i].type, Body: files_arr[i]};

        //try the upload function if it failes, catch it
        try {
            //await for upload to finish
            await upload(params);
        }
        catch (e) {
            //increment ErrNum if upload failed.
            ErrNum++;
        }

        if (i === files_arr.length-1 && ErrNum > 0) {
            //do something
        }
        else if (i === files_arr.length-1 && ErrNum === 0){
            alert("Success!");
        }
    }

    //I think it is more efficient if you put your if statements here
    if (ErrNum > 0) {
        //do something
    }
    else {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

If you read about promises and understand it is more efficient to do the uploads all at once with Promises.all();

I hope this helped, good luck!